# How did git(-svn) set correct links to svn:externals?

Tags: git, git-svn, svn-externals

This is not a question about something not working, it is a question to understand why something is working. Here is my setup:

```
projects
   |
   |--- mylibs
   | 
   |--- main
```

I have two different, unrelated `git-svn` checkouts `mylibs` and `main`. They were clones from very different places in the repositories. Now, a `svn commit` was made by someone else in which an external has been added in `main` to point to `mylibs` (i.e. a `svn` checkout of `main` would contain a directory `mylibs`, which is an external to `mylibs`).

Just out of curiosity I changed into `main` and did a `git svn rebase` just to see what git would do with the externals. `git` created a link as follows:

```
mylibs -> ../mylibs
```

which is what I want , but I do not know how this is possible. Because the local git checkout of `main` does not know that in the upper directory is a checkout of `mylibs`.

Is this a new feature? Does git know of all local clones/checkouts on my local disk/home directory?

Comment: I'm not sure how this happened but I'm almost certain that git-svn is not setting this up.  Perhaps the user you refer to didn't set up an external, but a symlink?

Comment: On viewvc it are definitively externals.

Comment: What version of git are you using?  I don't see how this would happen in what's currently on git's master branch... but I may be missing something.

Comment: It's git version 1.7.9.5. I am pretty sure I did not miss something important myself - but cannot exclude it 100%.